# Is there a way to log a user out from Zoom from the command line?

Tags: zoom-meeting

We are trying to automate Zoom login management in conference rooms at our office. We want to log off Zoom once the appointment time for a meeting is complete. Is there a way to log off Zoom using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have "business-like" zoom, the meeting can go as long as you wish. So Zoom will not close out by itself - it does not know when to close.

So the Host closes the meeting and when the Host closes the meeting, everyone's Zoom closes.

I am not sure why or where a command line would come into this.

I really do not know of any way for a process besides the actual Host to automate logoff outside of Host control.

If the Host needs to leave, they hand over control to a suub-Host.

That is the way all of my (numerous) Zoom meetings work.

This article may also help.

> From that Participants menu, the host or the person the host assigned can mouse over a participant’s name,
> and several options will appear, including Remove. That will log the user out.

[Remove participant](https://blog.zoom.us/keep-uninvited-guests-out-of-your-zoom-event/)

Comment: I am not referring to somebody leaving the meeting. After the host ends the call, there is no more call going on, but zoom is still logged in. If the user in the conference room does not log of zoom, it stays logged in. If the user left the room, zoom continues to stay logged in. I am trying to sign the user out of zoom

Comment: You need to be host or assigned by host. Another person cannot.  "Remove unwanted or disruptive participants: From that Participants menu, you can mouse over a participant's name, and several options will appear, including Remove" .  I amended my answer to include the method to remove a participant.

Comment: You're talking about the user being logged into Zoom, even though the actual meeting is over, @VinayPradhan? Is there any need for them to log into Zoom in the first place? It's perfectly possible to join a meeting with an anonymous account, isn't it?